# I want to create multiple Paint apps which are synchronized so that a picture drawn in any Paint board is drawn identically in all other Paint boards

Tags: java, networking, server

[image]Here is my Drawing Board code:

```
package drawing;
import java.awt.BasicStroke;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseMotionAdapter;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.Socket;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.Vector;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

class Point2 {
    int x, y;
    boolean noEnd = true;

    public Point2(int x, int y) {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

}

public class DrawingBoard extends JFrame {
    final static int ServerPort = 5002;
    DataInputStream is;
    DataOutputStream os;
    int x, y;
    Vector<Point2> list = new Vector<>();
    Point2 oldP=new Point2(0, 0), newP;

    class MyPanel extends JPanel {
        public MyPanel() {
            addMouseMotionListener(new MouseMotionAdapter() {
                public void mouseDragged(MouseEvent event) {
                    x = event.getX();
                    y = event.getY();
                    newP = new Point2(x, y);
                    list.add(newP);
                    repaint();
                    oldP = newP;
                    try {
                        String update = "";
                        for (Point2 point : list) {
                            update += point.x + "," + point.y + ",";
                        }
                        os.writeUTF(update);
                        os.flush();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                public void mouseMoved(MouseEvent event) {
                    if(list.size() != 0)
                        list.elementAt(list.size()-1).noEnd = false;
                }
                });
        }

        public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
            g2.setStroke(new BasicStroke(5));
            if(list.size()>=2 && list.elementAt(list.size()-2).noEnd)
                g2.drawLine(list.elementAt(list.size()-2).x, list.elementAt(list.size()-2).y, list.elementAt(list.size()-1).x, list.elementAt(list.size()-1).y);
        }
    }

    public DrawingBoard() throws IOException {
        InetAddress ip = InetAddress.getByName("localhost");
        Socket s = new Socket(ip, ServerPort);
        is = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
        os = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

        Thread thread2 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                while (true) {
                    try {
                        String update = is.readUTF();
                        processDrawingUpdate(update);
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        });
        thread2.start();

        setSize(600, 450);
        setTitle("My Paint");
        add(new MyPanel());
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }
    private void processDrawingUpdate(String update) {
        StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(update, ",");
        while (tokenizer.hasMoreTokens()) {
            int newX = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
            int newY = Integer.parseInt(tokenizer.nextToken());
            Point2 receivedPoint = new Point2(newX, newY);
            list.add(receivedPoint);
        }
        repaint();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        DrawingBoard p = new DrawingBoard();
    }
}
```

And this is my server code:

```
package drawing;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;

public class Server {

    static ArrayList<ServerThread> list = new ArrayList<>();

    static int clientCount = 0;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        ServerSocket ssocket = new ServerSocket(5002);

        Socket s;

        while (true) {
            s = ssocket.accept();

            DataInputStream is = new DataInputStream(s.getInputStream());
            DataOutputStream os = new DataOutputStream(s.getOutputStream());

            ServerThread thread = new ServerThread(s, "client " + clientCount, is, os);
            list.add(thread);
            thread.start();     
            clientCount++;

        }
    }
}

class ServerThread extends Thread {
    Scanner scn = new Scanner(System.in);
    private String name;
    final DataInputStream is;
    final DataOutputStream os;
    Socket s;
    boolean active;

    public ServerThread(Socket s, String name, DataInputStream is, DataOutputStream os) {
        this.is = is;
        this.os = os;
        this.name = name;
        this.s = s;
        this.active = true;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        String message;
        while (true) {
            try {
                message = is.readUTF();
                System.out.println(message);
                if (message.equals("logout")) {
                    this.active = false;
                    this.s.close();
                    break;
                }
                sendDrawingUpdate(message);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
        try {
            this.is.close();
            this.os.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void sendDrawingUpdate(String update) {
        for (ServerThread t : Server.list) {
            if (t != this) { 
                try {
                    t.os.writeUTF(update);
                    t.os.flush();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem with my code is when I draw in a board, only a dot of my mouse appears on other boards. So I want to know where the problem lies in these 2 code files and what i'm lacking. I know these codes look very clumsy but because this is what my professor gave me so I will clean all the unnecessary part later cause I want to focus on fixing this problem first!

Comment: This very well might be a thread issue.  `list` should be changed in the AWT event dispatch thread only.  Try replacing list.add(receivedPoint) with `EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> list.add(receivedPoint));`.  (There are more efficient ways to do this, but I don’t think that’s a significant goal of this project.)

Comment: @VGR The problem still remains the same, I really want to show you the picture of my problem but I don't really know how.

Comment: @VGR I just edited my problem so maybe it will be clearer now.

Answer (score 0):

There are many bad practices in this code.

- Don't use `Vector`, use `ArrayList` instead.
- Don't concatenate strings in a loop, use `StringBuilder`, or better yet change your protocol so points are separated by a newline character and just write them one at a time.
- Don't do I/O on the Event Dispatch Thread.

In your `mouseMoved` method you are setting the `noEnd` flag of the last point in the list.  But this flag is not sent via your protocol, and even if it was, you have already sent the point before you change the flag to false.

I would re-think your protocol.  Consider one point per line, and send a line that reads "end" to signal when the points are discontinuous.

Your `paintComponent` method only draws the last segment of the list.  Instead iterate over the entire list to draw everything.  The component does not "remember" what you painted before. It needs to know how to redraw itself entirely from a blank slate.

Comment: While your bullet points are all true, I think it’s worth noting that this is a learning project, and those considerations might be for a more advanced stage of software development.